# Как изменить содержание метки у мультироута

Tags: yandex-maps-api

можно ли как-то прокинуть параметр в роде `<div>{{options.anyValue}}</div>` в переменную `wayPointStartIconContentLayout`? или изменять ее вручную при каких-то изменениях? Можно ли получить адрес и сразу его туда прокинуть? У меня получается получить адрес только в случае, если я точки маршрута изначально текстом указываю.

Comment: Не понимаю какая задача стоит. Если вы хотите, чтобы в точках заданных координатами автоматически появлялся адрес, вам нужно задать параметр multiRoute.model.setParams({reverseGeocoding: true}); Если вы хотите чтобы после построения маршрута в метке было написано что-то, что вы зададите то нужно поменять стандартную метку, на другую. В песочнице есть пример https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/multiroute_view_options

Comment: @se0ga `reverseGeocoding` то, что надо! Это в документации где-то есть?

Comment: Да, конечно. https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/IMultiRouteParams-docpage/#field_detail__reverseGeocoding

Comment: @se0ga и могу ли я получить адреса точек в `requestsuccess`?

Comment: Если только спросить напрямую вроде как multiRoute.model.getWayPoints()[0].properties.get('address')

Comment: @se0ga то, что надо! Спасибо)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы хотите, чтобы в точках заданных координатами автоматически появлялся адрес, вам нужно задать параметр `multiRoute.model.setParams({reverseGeocoding: true});`  https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/IMultiRouteParams-docpage/#field_detail__reverseGeocoding